# Print random lines of file but with maximum count of a certain value

Tags: text-processing, scripting, gawk

I have a input file from which I want to randomly choose a line. In a column in every line is a value, and I want only a number of lines up to a maximum count of this value to be choosen randomly, not more.

So for simplicity, I started with a test file that looks like this:

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 2
6 2
7 3
8 4
9 4
10 4
11 5
12 5
13 5
14 5
15 5
16 6
17 6
18 7
19 8
20 8
```

Now I want to choose randomly lines, but only a maximum of for example 1 line per value in column 2:

```
1 1
6 2
7 3
9 4
13 5
17 6
18 7
19 8
```

This is the code I wrote to choose lines up to a maximum count:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i>0;i<8;i++))
do
gawk -v i="${i}" 'BEGIN{n=1} {if (i==$2 && n<=1) {n++;print $0;} if (n>1){next}} ' input >> output
done
```

How can I extend this to pick random lines up to the maximum?

Comment: Run the input through `shuf` first, that gives you the lines in random order? Then use `awk` to pick lines until you have one of each desired value. Alternatively, for each value, have `awk` (or `grep`) print all lines with that value, then `shuf -n 1` to pick one out of those.

Comment: Are the numbers in the second column always non-decreasing?

Comment: @frostschutz I guess your second solution my problem could could be useful for my purpose. Thanks for the input! But is the statistics of `shuffle`the same as a random pick with replacement?
@choroba Yes they are. These numbers stand for classes in which the lines are sort in. In my file they are currently not sorted by class number, but this is no problem to do.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sort`, for 1 as the maximum:

```
sort -R file | sort -uk2,2
```

For arbitrary values as the maximum:

```
sort -R file | awk -v max=2 '++count[$2] <= max' | head -n 8
```